# Eclipse JavaDoc LaTeX equations

Tags: java, eclipse, latex, javadoc

I have code where it's common to have many equations in JavaDoc comments. I'm currently using MathML to display these equations, as it's the only way I've been able to get equations that can display in Eclipse's hover tooltips.

I don't actually care about created HTML. I just need Eclipse's hover to display equations correctly.

Unfortunately, MathML is **insanely** verbose. One line of *simple* LaTeX becomes 50 lines of MathML! It's cluttering up my source and the JavaDoc comments are unreadable in the source code (you *have* to hover over the method to read the comment).

Does anyone know a way to use LaTeX equations in Eclipse that will show up in this hover text?

EDIT: Something like [this](http://zverovich.net/2012/01/14/beautiful-math-in-javadoc.html) would be preferable, but this doesn't work in Eclipse's hovers. Presumably there's no way to inject JavaScript in those.

Comment: Eclipse disabled JavaScript in hovers due to the potiential for malicious exploits. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=228608 I don't know if you could somehow selectively re-enable it. This would seem to be the most straightforward option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggestion 1: Use MathJax**

I use MathJax to write LaTeX equations in JavaDoc. You may see the result here:
https://javadoc.io/static/net.finmath/finmath-lib/6.0.12/net.finmath.lib/net/finmath/montecarlo/interestrate/models/LIBORMarketModelFromCovarianceModel.html

However, MathJax relies on JavaScript and the Eclipse Hover does not support JavaScript. But then I must say that the MathJax LaTeX can be read even without renderer, so for me it is OK to have LaTeX code in the hover text. You will see it if you enable JavaScript in the hover text - but that is a different question.

To enable MathJax you just need to include a header in your docket config like

```
                <header>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
                    </script>
                    ]]>
                </header>
```

**Suggestion 2: Use CLSI on your local machine**

If you need this only for yourself you could run a [CLSI](https://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/) (common-latex-service-interface). Then, maybe it is possible to just have an image tag with the latex code in its URL which returns an image). I have not elaborated on this... (personally I would prefer option 1, because it will also generate the LaTeX in the JavaDoc.

Comment: I did try that, as noted in the post. I'm very on the edge, however, about how readable LaTeX is in the JavaDoc comments. It should be noted that the code I'm using uses the Eclipse JavaDoc hover heavily, but doesn't currently use the HTML JavaDocs. As well, complicated formulas can still be somewhat difficult to read in LaTeX (although better than MathML).

Comment: One "solution" I'm considering is converting the LaTeX to an image and including that image in the JavaDoc (Eclipse will display images) with the LaTeX code as the image's alt text (for ease of updating the image in the future). I really would prefer a way to automatically generate the equations images directly from the JavaDocs, though.

Comment: Converting it to an image is what MathJax does. Converts it on the fly. If you convert it in a preprocessing you will have an ugly image tag and - I assume that you like to keep the latex for editing - the raw latex too. I believe it should be possible to enable JavaScript processing in Eclipse hover and solve the problem that way.

Comment: True, but the issue is getting the image to display in Eclipse's hover. I've already tried MathJax, and Eclipse doesn't execute JS in the hovers. This works for the HTML output only (which I'm not using).

Comment: I added CLSI to my answer, which might help you in creating that image (e.g. via REST like server).

Comment: The CLSI solution works. Although instead of running a local server, I used CodeCog's Latex-to-image service. It's not perfect: I'd prefer a local solution that doesn't require installing additional software, but it works. The URLs are *almost* LaTeX (spaces and plus signs are encoded), so it's mostly editable. I can also swap this out for a local service in the future, if needed.

Comment: To elaborate, one can then include, for example, `<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\frac{x&space;&plus;&space;2}{\pi}" />` in their JavaDocs. Eclipse is able to properly display this as an image, and the LaTeX is in the URL in a somewhat readable fashion.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you don't have to encode the spaces and + signs. `<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\frac{x + 2}{\pi}" />` works fine. This is much more readable and would allow you to easily edit the equation directly in the JavaDoc comment. Of course, the spaces are encoded as `%20` by the software (eg, the browser), but work correctly in source code, anyway.

Comment: This is interesting. I would prefer the first solution, but maybe I try out the CLSI solution myself.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).

Answer (score 2):

You can try `LaTeXlet`

Take a look at: http://users.informatik.uni-halle.de/~grau/LaTeXlet/

LaTeXlet is a taglet that allows to use LaTeX within Javadoc comments.

Here are an Example:

http://users.informatik.uni-halle.de/~grau/LaTeXlet/doc/latexlet/BlockLaTeXlet.html

Comment: I've tried this one, as well, and couldn't find a way to get it to display in Eclipse's hover. Can you confirm that this displays in the hover, and explain how to configure Eclipse to use a taglet in the hover?